# Why does a Template function made using relational operator in C++ not work correctly for strings?

Tags: c++, string, templates, typename, relational-operators

This is a simple code that returns max of two inputs to practice the use of Template functions in C++. The code prints output as "Hello" which is wrong, and when we uncomment the line {string s = "Hello";}, the output becomes correct, even though the "Hello" used is not s.
[The screenshot of code run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFmfu.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T maxx(T a, T b)
{
    if (a>b) {return a;}
    return b;
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    // string s = "Hello";
    cout<<maxx("Hello","World")<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the result I get http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0d49dd7e56eee82

Comment: @JonathanPotter Pure accident. As arrays decaying to pointers, we effectively compare their addresses, and where the underlying arrays are stored is unspecified...

Answer (score 4):

The template parameter of the template function is deduced to `const char *` due to this call

```
maxx("Hello","World")
```

So pointers to first characters of the string literals are compared. The result of the comparison depends on the order in which the compiler placed literals in the literal pool.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the other answer, the `maxx` function gets `const char *` as arguments, so you compare pointers, and the result depends on in which order the compiler places `Hello` and `World` in the data section.

So why does the order change when you do uncomment `string s = "Hello";`? Because you introduce another `const char *` with the value `Hello` when you do `= "Hello"` and the compiler will use the same address for the other `Hello` of `maxx("Hello","World")` as those const char must not be changed and `gcc` seems to evaluate the arguments of `maxx("Hello", "World")` from back to front.

So for `gcc`:

```
int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    // string s = "Hello";
    cout<<maxx("Hello","World")<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

will result in this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "World"
.LC1:
        .string "Hello"
.LC2:
        .string "\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, 0
        call    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(bool)
        mov     esi, 0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin+16
        call    std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::tie(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    char const* maxx<char const*>(char const*, char const*)
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

If you now uncomment `string s = "Hello";`, it will result in:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hello"
.LC1:
        .string "World"
.LC2:
        .string "\n"
main:
        …
```

as the `Hello` is in this case found first in `string s = "Hello";` before `maxx("Hello","World")` is evaluated, so `Hello` is, in this case, the first const string added to the data section then `World`.

If you would add a `string s2 = "World";` before your `string s` then the order would change again:

```
    string s2 = "World";
    string s = "Hello";
    cout<<maxx("Hello","World")<<"\n";
```

```
.LC0:
        .string "World"
.LC1:
        .string "Hello"
.LC2:
        .string "\n"
main:
    …
```